# how to insert rows into gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Sir,
I want to have an insert link functionality to insert rows into gridview As we have auto generate edit and delete in gridview in asp.net,. how to do it?can u also provide me the links.

Comment: Have you tried this ? : http://myurl.in/KmiyG

Comment: You don't insert the rows into the gridview - you insert the rows into the data store underlying the gridview...

Answer (score 0):

Hope i have understood your question and this solution might help you..

Solution:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="2" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" AutoGenerateEditButton="true"
DataKeyNames="theID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" >
<PagerSettings  Mode=NumericFirstLast />
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="Default2.aspx">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
   </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="theID" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="theID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="theName" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="theName" />
</Columns>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Use databinding to insert the row in theposition you want and after bind it to control, if you're talking about WindowsForms.
2. If youare talking about WPF, do the same :)
3. If you use ASP.NET insert the row into the binded data and "rebind" it.

Comment: @Eranga: I'm surprised how I didn't see it before, may be it was edited after... By the way I updated answer.